# Como usar o collapse no bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, collapse, sidebar

```
<html lang="pt-br">
<body>

    <?php 
    include_once 'header.php';
    ?>
    <?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION["email"]) || !isset($_SESSION["senha"])){
        header("Location: logar.php");
        exit;
    }else{

    }
    ?>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Estilo/css/sidebar.css"/>
    <div>
    <section>
        <hr class="m-0 mt-4">
    <div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">

    <!-- Sidebar -->

    <div class="bg-light border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">

      <div class="sidebar-heading"><?php echo $_SESSION["nome"] ?> </div>
      <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Meus dados</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Preferências</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Segurança</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Events</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Profile</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Status</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid" id="menu-toggle">


        <h1 class="mt-4">Simple Sidebar</h1>
        <p>The starting state of the menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will change.</p>
        <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>. The top navbar is optional, and just for demonstration. Just create an element with the <code>#menu-toggle</code> ID which will toggle the menu when clicked.</p>
      </div>


  </div>
    </section>
  </div>

    <?php  
    include_once 'footer.php';
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Então eu estou usando essa sidebar que eu encontrei no github, e como sou novato nisso queria saber como fazer com que o menu desapareça quando a tela diminuir, igual o navbar do bootstrap, não tenho certeza mas acho que é a função collapse que faz isso. Então como eu faço para usa-lá na sidebar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi vc quer usar o componente de `toggle` da `navbar` do Bootstrap na sua sidebar correto. Para isso vc tem que usar algumas propriedades da nav na sua `sidebar` como  `navbar-expand-lg`, além disso vc precisa inserir no HTML o `button` que vai fazer o `toggle` para expandir e *collapsar* a `sidebar`. nesse exemplo usei o próprio `button` do Bootstrap, mas vc pode customiza-lo se quiser...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" />
<style>

</style>
</head>

<body>


    <div>
        <section>
            <hr class="m-0 mt-4">
            <div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">

                <!-- Sidebar -->
                <div class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">
                    <button class="navbar-toggler align-self-start" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

                        <div class="sidebar-heading"><?php echo $_SESSION["nome"] ?> </div>
                        <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Meus dados</a>
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Preferências</a>
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Segurança</a>
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Events</a>
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Profile</a>
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Status</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

                <!-- Page Content -->
                <div id="page-content-wrapper">
                    <div class="container-fluid" id="menu-toggle">


                        <h1 class="mt-4">Simple Sidebar</h1>
                        <p>The starting state of the menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will change.</p>
                        <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>. The top navbar is optional, and just for demonstration. Just create an element with the <code>#menu-toggle</code> ID which will toggle the menu when clicked.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </section>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```